# RStudio Shiny renderDataTable single column with no header

Tags: datatables, shiny, rstudio

Is there a way in RStudio Shiny to use `renderDataTable` to print a single column table with no header?

Or alternatively, is there a way to output a single column dataframe and have a `Copy to Clipboard` button somewhere?

Comment: I assume that you'd want a copy-to-clipboard solution to exclude the header?

Comment: That's correct. I don't mind what type of display it is as long as I can (1) see it on the screen and (2) click on a "Copy to Clipboard" button with no header.

Comment: it seems copying to clipboard will require some JS dependencies. Another option might be to add a textarea box with the data in addition to the datatables output that the user could highlight and copy with Ctrl+C.

Comment: I got copy to the clipboard with extensions, but I can't get rid of the header...